# Will time exist in heat of the universe?

Tags: spacetime, time, universe

Will there be any sense of time during the heat death of universe? Since there is no interesting events I think you cannot measure time.

Comment: There will be interesting events. One it will have beginning and an end. Moreover there will be uneven distribution of heat because of the non homogeneous nature of matter which is giving of the heat... sometimes there will be sudden flare sometimes there will be an explosion... u can compare the scenario with Sun...time can be measured on Sun ...therefore there will a sense of time during heat death of Universe...

Comment: @SacrificialEquation During the heat death, things are very homogeneous, there aren't any major energy differences, so there isn't anything capable of causing an explosion. There's just a uniform bath of low energy photons.

Comment: @PM2Ring ok. I beg to disagree because I was told by someone very familiar with the subject that in beginning Universe was a very hot soup ... everything so uniform yet we see interesting things like rotating and revolving earth sun moon .... clearly things were not homogeneous then ... why should it be when universe dies ??

Comment: The difference is that the soup is a lot thinner, and colder, less than a trillionth of a degree above absolute zero. Even small stellar mass black holes won't start losing mass through Hawking radiation until the CMB is colder than a nanokelvin, and the SMBHs  are even colder. The heat death doesn't really start until all the black holes have totally evaporated. OTOH, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology